# Функция, сокращающая однообразный код js

Tags: javascript

Предположим, есть такой код:

```
draw.cube().color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);
draw.circle().color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);
draw.rect().color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);
```

Хочу пометить, что это не jQuery.
Как вы заметили `.color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);`
в каждой строчке повторяется.
Вопрос: как сократить код до примерно такого:

```
draw.cube().setParams();
draw.circle().setParams();
draw.rect().setParams();

function setParams = ... ?
```

Comment: _Хочу пометить, что это не jQuery_ - а стоило пометить. что это на самом деле за объекты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы method chaining имели в виду?

```js
var Geometry = function(type) {
  this._type = type;
  this._color = 'transparent';
  this._size = 1;
  this._rotation = 0;
  this._scale = 1;
};

Geometry.prototype = {
  constructor: Geometry,
  setColor: function(color) {
    this._color = color;
    return this;
  },
  setSize: function(size) {
    this._size = size;
    return this;
  },
  setRotation: function(rotation) {
    this._rotation = rotation;
    return this;
  },
  setScale: function(scale) {
    this._scale = scale;
    return this;
  },
  setParams: function(settingObject) {
    this.setColor(settingObject.color);
    this.setSize(settingObject.size);
    this.setRotation(settingObject.rotation);
    this.setScale(settingObject.scale);
    return this;
  },
  toString: function() {
    return 'This is ' + this._type + ': color=' + this._color + ' size=' + this._size + ' rotation=' + this._rotation + ' scale=' + this._scale;
  }
}

var Draw = function() {};

Draw.prototype = {
  constructor: Draw,
  cube: function() {
    return new Geometry('cube')
  },
  circle: function() {
    return new Geometry('circle')
  },
  rect: function() {
    return new Geometry('rect')
  }
}

var draw = new Draw();

var cube1 = draw.cube().setColor('red').setRotation('20deg').setSize(2).setScale(0.25);
var cube2 = draw.cube().setParams({
  color: 'red',
  rotation: '20deg',
  size: 2,
  scale: 0.25
});

console.log(cube1.toString());
console.log(cube2.toString());
```

Или дополнительный метод для упрощения назначения свойств

```js
var setParams = function(geometry, settingObject) {
  geometry
    .setColor(settingObject.color)
    .setSize(settingObject.size)
    .setRotation(settingObject.rotation)
    .setScale(settingObject.scale);
};

var Geometry = function(type) {
  this._type = type;
  this._color = 'transparent';
  this._size = 1;
  this._rotation = 0;
  this._scale = 1;
};

Geometry.prototype = {
  constructor: Geometry,
  setColor: function(color) {
    this._color = color;
    return this;
  },
  setSize: function(size) {
    this._size = size;
    return this;
  },
  setRotation: function(rotation) {
    this._rotation = rotation;
    return this;
  },
  setScale: function(scale) {
    this._scale = scale;
    return this;
  },
  toString: function() {
    return 'This is ' + this._type + ': color=' + this._color + ' size=' + this._size + ' rotation=' + this._rotation + ' scale=' + this._scale;
  }
}

var Draw = function() {};

Draw.prototype = {
  constructor: Draw,
  cube: function() {
    return new Geometry('cube')
  },
  circle: function() {
    return new Geometry('circle')
  },
  rect: function() {
    return new Geometry('rect')
  }
}

var draw = new Draw();

var cube1 = draw.cube().setColor('red').setRotation('20deg').setSize(2).setScale(0.25);
var cube2 = draw.cube();

setParams(cube2, {
  color: 'red',
  rotation: '20deg',
  size: 2,
  scale: 0.25
});

console.log(cube1.toString());
console.log(cube2.toString());
```

Или добавить метод в прототип

```
Geometry.prototype.setParams = function(settingObject) {
  this.setColor(settingObject.color)
    .setSize(settingObject.size)
    .setRotation(settingObject.rotation)
    .setScale(settingObject.scale);
  return this;
};
```

Или унаследовать класс и расширить его функциональность

```
var GeometryExt = function() {
  Geometry.apply(this, arguments);
};

GeometryExt.prototype = Object.create(Geometry.prototype);
GeometryExt.prototype.setParams = function(settingObject) {
  this.setColor(settingObject.color)
    .setSize(settingObject.size)
    .setRotation(settingObject.rotation)
    .setScale(settingObject.scale);
  return this;
};

var cubeExt = new GeometryExt('Mega-cube');
cubeExt.setParams({
  color: 'red',
  rotation: '20deg',
  size: 2,
  scale: 0.25
});
```

Comment: Мне подошло бы здесь добавление метода в прототип, но я это пытался сделать еще до обращения на форум. Ситуация такая: у меня есть уже готовый класс который я беру из файла.  
`draw = SVG(‘drawing’)`  
Но перед этим я пытаюсь расширить этот класс:  
`SVG.prototype.colorIt = function(){ ... return this; }`
В итоге при вызове
`draw.rect().colorIt()` получаю `colorIt' is undefined`

Comment: @igolka97 правильно - потому что вы добавили метод `draw.colorIt`, а не `draw.rect().colorIt`. Вам надо за манки-патчить класс, отвечающий за одну фигуру, а не за весь SVG. Только имейте в виду: monkey patch [ведет к проблемам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B).

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как запатчить все фигуры разом?

Comment: @igolka97 скорее всего, у них должен быть базовый класс, осталось только найти его.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а, точно, щас найду. Только не представляю как будет выглядеть код когда я найду базовый класс.

Comment: @PavelMayorov все фигуры наследуют класс `SVG.Shape`

Comment: @igolka97 ну так и расширяйте его

Comment: @PavelMayorov пожалуйста, дайте ссыль где прочитать об этом

Comment: Вы, случайно, не [такой библиотекой](https://github.com/wout/svg.js) пользуетесь? Если ей или аналогом, можно добавить метод в исходники и собрать ее. Либо найти в исходниках [класс rect](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/rect.js), заглянуть в [базовый класс shape](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/shape.js) и подумать куда добавить нужный код.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую и я внести 5 копеек

```
let elements = [];
elements.push(draw.cube());
elements.push(draw.circle());
elements.push(draw.rect());

element.forEach((element) => {
     element.color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще. Нужно написать функцию и в нее передавать объекты.

```js
function setParams(shape){
  shape.color(‘white’).size(100).rotate(50).scale(2);
}

// затем вызваем так
setParams(draw.cube());
setParams(draw.circle());
setParams(draw.rect());
```

Comment: Подошло бы, но мне нужно вызывать функцию обращаясь к новосозданным методам класса, а не использовать функциональный вид.

Comment: @igolka97 А откуда такое странное требование?

Comment: @PavelMayorov о, я тоже Майоров :D А вот, слишком много рефакторить уже существующий код тогда надо будет. Если ничего не получится, то лучше все оставить как есть с тонной строчек :P